# How to save dynamic data in database in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My project is on angularjs+Laravel.

From frontend I am sending dynamically generated input to laravel controller.

Scenario is I am taking family details where child field is dynamic.So if you click of Add more It will generate another input field.

Initially Person X have 1 child namely ROohan . Now he Have 2 more, Now when he is sending data of 3 new children, I want that 2 children data get added without over writing present 2 children.

My request which I am receiving in controller

```
family_data : 
      {"famdet":[{"id":"choice1","cname":"Rohan","doa":"2017-01-12"},  
       {"id":"choice2","cname":"sohan","cdob":"2017-01-13"},           
       {"id":"choice3","cname":"nitesh","cdob":"2017-01-07"}
          ]}
```

my problem is How to make this data save in separate row and if data is present then row should not be get created.

Comment: Create a model and corresponding database table. Then loop through each of the inputs, check it the models already exist and if not, create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use `json_decode()` to convert data to an array, for example:

```
$familyData = json_decode($data, true)['famdet'];
```

Then you should iterate over this array and use [`updateOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#other-creation-methods) method to update existing rows or create new ones. For example, if you're using and ID to identify a row:

```
foreach ($familyData as $row) {
    Model::updateOrCreate(['id' => $row['id']], $row)
}
```

Comment: can you please elobrate more. I am not getting proper output.  @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: How can I remove the field from table if user has removed some particular data. @AlexeyMezenin